# WebDriver SelectElement appears not to be working

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am new to Selenium and trying to get to grips with manipulating dropdown lists. I couldn’t get the .SelectBy methods to work so I thought I’d go back to basics and list the contents of a dropdown list using the SelectElement.Options method.

I have the following html with a page as a dropdown of countries,

```
<select name="ddlCountry" id=" ddlCountry>
<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select ...</option>
<option value="231">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
...
<option value="246">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

I then have the following code to list out the text for each option.

```
var dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("phMainContent_EmployeeAdd1_ddlCountry"));
var selectItem = new SelectElement(dropdown);
var options = selectItem.Options;
foreach (var option in options)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(option.Text); 
}
```

When I interrogate the options variable it holds a list of the expected number of options. However, when you look at the “text” property of each option in the list it is blank! Why?

Supplementary question how would I list the **Value** and **Index** properties of each option, as there only appears to be the **Text** property?

I’m hoping once this is explained I’ll know why the following does not work to select an item in a list.

```
/// <summary>
/// WebDriver: Select an element in a dropdown
/// </summary>
/// <param name="driver">WebDriver object</param>
/// <param name="dropdownlist">Name of dropdown (by ID)</param>
/// <param name="text">Text of item to be selected</param>
/// <returns>None</returns>
public static void SelectItemInDropdownByIdByText(IWebDriver driver, string dropdownlist, string text)
{
    var dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id(dropdownlist));
    var selectItem = new SelectElement(dropdown);
    selectItem.SelectByValue(text);
}
```

Called by

```
SelectItemInDropdownByIdByText(driver, "ddlCountry", "United Kingdom");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

[`selectItem.SelectByText`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/SelectElement.cs#L135)

The thing you have to understand, is `<select>`'s use the Value *also* to determine the text.  Selenium treats these differently however. Take this for example:

```
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

let `test = <select id="test">`

```
test.SelectByValue("2") // selects <option value="2">
test.SelectByText("Three") // selects <option value="3">
test.Options[1].Text // the Text is actually the `textContent` of the node, which is "Two"
text.Options[0].GetAttribute("value") // 1
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to list out the option properties using - Debug.WriteLine(option.GetAttribute("value") + " : " + option.GetAttribute("index") + " : " + option.GetAttribute("text"));

Comment: @sircafpsalot, However when I tried to use the SelectByText method to select an item in the dropdown it failed. The var dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddl_Country")); finds the select. The next line   var selectItem = new SelectElement(dropdown); fails. And ultimately the exception "Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated" is thrown.

Comment: I've just had a closer look at the code (not mine) and I have noticed the **select** has a style="display: none" which might explain why it is not visible to be manipulated. Would this be a legitimate reason for the SelectElement(dropdown) failing? The coders have used another implementation for the dropdown, which I'll now need to figure out!

Comment: yep. that would be a reason for it failing.  the element has to be humanly visible and interactable.